# Getting unresolved errors from header file and declaration issues

Tags: c++

I get the general idea of header files but can't seem to figure out why in the code below I can create a vector in the main cpp? can someone explain if it is syntax or a linking issue maybe? I thought I defined it in the header file but after trying several different ways I can't get it to work. Guidance would be appreciated. the program will compile but wont go past outputting hello world, the error says symbol vector could not be resolved. this I don't understand since i have #include  at the top

```
#include "helloworld.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
namespace std {

hello_world::hello_world() {
    std::vector<int> g1;

}

hello_world::~hello_world() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

} //namespace std 
int main() {
    std::cout<<"hello world lets get this right";
    vector<int> g1;



#pragma once
#include <vector>

namespace std {

class hello_world {
public:
    hello_world();
    virtual ~hello_world();

    std::vector<int>;
};

} /* namespace std */
```

Comment: The error message you get would reveal what kind of issue you have (syntax, linking, other). However, you did not include that in your question...

Comment: Why are you placing your own code inside `namespace std`?

Comment: that's where I need some clarification so eclipse auto generated a header file and the namespace with hello_world::hello_world(){  I have tried putting the int main and following code inside hello_world() and before it neither has worked I guess I simple don't understand what the purpose of the header and Hello_world namespace in this setup and why it keeps causing simple library calls like cout and vector to get screwed up?

Answer (score 0):

By no means are you allowed to declare your own functions, classes, methods etc. in `namespace std;`. Who taught you that?

Comment: ok so I'm migrating over from learning coding basics in java so here I just created a new class within a project like I did in java this causes eclipse to auto-generate namespace std{ and the Hello_World::Hello_World(). Here I am confused I haven't seen this in the c/c++ text book or internet examples .I have commented the whole auto generated code out and start from scratch but it causes errors and on the project tree it is the auto-generated sections that are flagged. how am I to use this auto code correctly so it doesn't cause these linking issues I'm having ?